# How to make the autocomplete Jquery UI plugin dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the Jquery UI autocomplete plugin from [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). The question, how do I insert dynamic content into the autocomplete? This is what I've tried:

```
<?php

  $db2 = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "crave crap");
  $one_grab = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM movies");

  echo '<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
    </script>';

    while($two_row = mysqli_fetch_array($one_grab)) {
    echo $two_row["title"];
  }

      echo '"ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $("#delete_movie").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>';

  ?>
```

Please assume that Jquery & Jquery UI are properly linked... To further explain, I have a while loop that is connected to an SQL query. I tried to append it to the autocomplete content, but this isn't working. What is the correct way to do this with the Jquery UI autocomplete plugin?

> **EDIT @Vijay Arun**
>
> This is the code you have published:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <?php

  $db2 = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "crave crap");
  $one_grab = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM movies");

 while($two_row = mysqli_fetch_array($one_grab)) {
    $data[] = $two_row["title"];
  }

  ?>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = "<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>";
    $("#delete_movie").autocomplete({
      source: JSON.parse(availableTags)
    });
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="delete_movie" name="delete_movie" required>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

> Does this look correct? If so, the code is still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`remote`](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) example , `echo json_encode()` at `php`

```
$("#delete_movie").autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/path/to/php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        q: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
      }
    });
 })
```

Comment: Great example! However, I want to keep the same styling used in the Jquery UI example.

Comment: _"want to keep the same styling used in the Jquery UI example"_ What is "the same styling" ? ? See original Question at _"The question, how do I insert dynamic content into the autocomplete?"_

Comment: The styled version uses nice spacing and highlighting. Your example only used text autocomplete...

Comment: @ProgrammingTree _"The styled version uses nice spacing and highlighting."_ Perhaps update Question with requirement described at comment ? _"want to keep the same styling used in the Jquery UI example"_ . Question at original post appear to be _"The question, how do I insert dynamic content into the autocomplete?"_ . Note also, solution at post should not affect styling of `.autocomplete()` widget; only addresses an approach to retrieve data from server when term searched by user

Answer (score 0):

you need two separate files,
`index.php` and `suggest.php`

`index.php`

```
<div class="ui-widget">
   <input id="delete_movie" name="delete_movie" required>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#delete_movie" ).autocomplete({
        source: "suggest.php"   
    });
</script>
```

`suggest.php`

```
<?php
    $db2 = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "crave crap");
    $one_grab = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%{$_GET['term']}%' ");
    while($two_row = mysqli_fetch_array($one_grab)) {
       $data[] = $two_row["title"];
    }
    echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: I just use an dummy data, u can do this with remote option

Comment: Would you mind explaining more? How do I make $data equal to while($two_row = mysqli_fetch_array($one_grab)) {
    echo $two_row["title"];
  }

Comment: @ProgrammingTree I have updated my answer lets look  into it,

Comment: I have updayed my question to reply to you. I have shown you the complete code which you have given me. Please tell me if the formatting looks correct. If so, the code is incorrect...

Comment: i have modified the answer

Comment: Code still doesn't work. I found the solution from a different source. I watched a YouTube playlist here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bd-niZKkOLE